# How to find out if the nla editor is in tweak mode

Tags: python, nla-editor

How can I verify with python if the current strip is in tweak mode?
I know I can call the operators `bpy.ops.nla.tweakmode_enter()` and `bpy.ops.nla.tweakmode_exit()` for entering and leaving. Is there something similar which tells me if I am already in this mode?

Comment: Just used the api search and it yielded [`Scene.is_nla_tweakmode`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=tweak#bpy.types.Scene.is_nla_tweakmode).

Comment: @pinkvertex Muchas Gracias :) Feel free to add it as an answer so I can mark the question as answered